# What does the notation $k_B^{\perp} $ ( or $\bar{k}_B^{\perp}$ ) in Peskin's Quantum field theory book (p.105) exactly means?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

I am reading the Peskin & Schroeder's An introduction to Quantum field theory, p.105~p.106 (Construction of a cross-section from the invariant matrix element (p.104) ) and I am confusing about definitions of some notations.

First, we are given (Cross section, their book, p.105, (4.76):)

$$ d\sigma =(\prod_f\frac{d^3p_f}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_f}) \int d^2b(\prod_{i=A,B}\int \frac{d^3k_i}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\phi_i(\vec{k}_i)}{\sqrt{2E_i}}\int \frac{d^3 \bar{k}_i}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\phi_i^{*}(\bar{\vec{k}}_i)}{\sqrt{2\bar{E}_i}})$$
$$\times e^{i\vec{b} \cdot (\bar{\vec{k}_B} - \vec{k}_B)} ( _{out}\langle \{\vec{p}_f\}|\{\vec{k}_i|\}\rangle_{in})( _{out}\langle \{\vec{p}_f\}|\{\bar{\vec{k}}_i|\rangle_{in})^*  \tag{4.76}.  $$

where we have used $\bar{k}_A$ and $\bar{k}_B$ as dummy integration variables in the second half of the squared amplitude.

Then he wrote,

" The $d^2 b$ integral can be performed to give a factor $(2\pi)^2 \delta^{(2)}(k_B^{\perp} - \bar{k}_B^{\perp})$. "

Here, I understand the $d^2 b$ integral as  $$ \int d^2\vec{b} e^{i\vec{b} \cdot (\vec{\bar{k}}_B-\vec{k}_B)} = (2\pi)^2 \delta^{(2)}(k_B^{\perp} - \bar{k}_B^{\perp}) $$

(C.f. https://professores.ift.unesp.br/ricardo.matheus/files/courses/2014tqc1/QFT1notes.pdf, p.176 )

**Q.** My question is, what's the definition of $k_B^{\perp}$ ( $\bar{k}_B^{\perp}$)? And if we know definitions, why the above $d^2 b$ -integration is true?

This question orginates from follows : In fact, my goal is next calculation. It is related to the Peskin's book, p.105. In the page, he wrote that "Of the six integrals, only those over $\bar{k}_A^{z}$ and $\bar{k}_B^{z}$ requrie some work. I undertand this sentence as follows

$$\int d^3\bar{k}_A \int d^3 \bar{k}_B \delta^{(4)}(\Sigma \bar{k}_i - \Sigma p_f) \delta^{(2)}(k_B^{\perp} - \bar{k}_B^{\perp}) $$
$$\stackrel{?}{=}  (k_i^{\perp} = \bar{k}_i^{\perp}) \times \int d \bar{k}^z_A d\bar{k}_B^{z} \delta(\bar{k}_A^{z} + \bar{k}_B^{z} - \Sigma p_f^{z}) \delta ( \bar{E}_A + \bar{E}_B - \Sigma E_f) $$

( C.f. Again, refer to https://professores.ift.unesp.br/ricardo.matheus/files/courses/2014tqc1/QFT1notes.pdf )

And in part, I can't make progress this integral by reason of ignorance about exact definition of $k_B^{\perp} $ ( or $\bar{k}_B^{\perp} )$. I think that this knowing of the definition is necessary step to perform the integral ).

Can anyone helps?

Comment: Doesn’t the $\perp$ indicate the part of the vector perpendicular to $\vec b$? (What else could it be?)

Comment: O. K. I correct. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think that we have $\vec{b} := ( b^x,b^y,b^z)$, $k_B = (k_B^{x}, k_B^{y}, k_B^{z})$ and $\bar{k}_B = (\bar{k}_B^{x}, \bar{k}_B^{y}, \bar{k}_B^{z})$. Can we express $k_B^{\perp}$, for example, via the components of $\vec{b}$, $k_B$ ( or $\bar{k}_B$ )? I want to figure out the truthness of the above integration formula by substituting concrete values of $\bar{k}_B^{\perp}$ and $k_B^{\perp}$ directly. So far, for me, those definitions are vague.

Comment: ${\vec k}^\perp=\vec k-(\vec k\cdot\hat b)\hat b$ (Notice the hats, indicating a unit vector.) The second term is the part of $\vec k$ that is parallel to $\vec b$. This is basic vector geometry. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

Comment: You also need to understand what $d^2\vec b$ (as opposed to $d^3\vec b$) means.

Comment: Oh! really? Thanks for pointing out. In fact I inadvertently used $d^2 \vec{b}$ as $db^{x} db^{y}$. But is that different from your intension?  Does $d^2 \vec{b}$ has different meaning from mine? What is exact definition for measure $d^3 \vec{b}$. Can you help me?

Comment: It seems that I should vefify the above $d^2 b$ -integral in my question definitely rigorously.

Comment: I don’t have a copy of P&S, so I’m not sure about what I’ve said. Maybe $\perp$ is indicating the part of the vector perpendicular to the beam direction and $d^2\vec b$ indicating integration over the plane perpendicular to the beam. I’ll let someone who understands this notation better than I do provide an answer.

Comment: Since $\vec b$ is being integrated over, it isn’t a single direction and therefore my very first comment is completely wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, Uhm Its okay. Thanks